# Query attributes, where one attribute is missing

Tags: sql, join

I have a question regarding a query.
There are two tables:

```
Objects table:
==============
Object ID   Date
1       2016-03-15
2       2016-01-20

Attributes table:
=================
Parent ID   Attribute   AttributeData
1       Size        XL
2       Size        S
2       Price       20

The query is to join the data to get this:
==========================================
Objet ID    Size    Price
1       XL  NULL
2       S   20

But I only get this:
==========================================
Objet ID    Size    Price
2       S   20
```

A LEFT JOIN doesn't help - because there is no entry in the attribute table for price for ID1.

I am sorry for beein such a newbie on this.

Glad for any help.

Steffen

Comment: Please post your existing query. Please also clarify what database you are using as this will affect the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think conditional aggregation does what you want:

```
select parentid,
       max(case when attribute = 'Size' then attributedata end) as size,
       max(case when attribute = 'Price' then attributedata end) as price
from attributes
group by parentid;
```

Using a `left join` you would do:

```
select o.*, s.attributedata as size, p.attributedata as price
from objects o left join
     attributes s
     on o.objectid = s.parentid and s.attribute = 'Size' left join
     attributes p
     on o.objectid = p.parentid and p.attribute = 'Price';
```

Note that for this to work, the condition on the attribute name needs to be in the `on` clause, not a `where` clause.